# Invalid parameters were supplied to Stripe API

Tags: php, laravel, stripe-payments

I am using following code

```
        $charge = \Stripe\Charge::create([
            'amount'        => 27, 
            'currency'      => 'eur',
            'description'   => 'Order ID is: 1',
            'source' => $request->all()['stripeToken']
        ]);
```

It is giving error because of amount.

Comment: amount is less than minimum allowed, you have 0.27 EUR which is less than 0.50 USD (minimum valid amount), just in case if you want to submit 27 EUR, use 2700

Comment: So each time should I multiply amount with 100 in the backend? i.e 'amount'   => $amount * 100,

Comment: I did not work with EUR, but most likely yes. For sure you need to do it with USD. General rule for unit is the smallest currency amount which is 1 cent, so should be amount in EUR by 100